# Add Google Calendar Event to non Primary calendar

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I am trying to add an event to a newly created calendar. The calendar can be created like so:

```
gapi.client.calendar.calendars.insert(
 {
     "resource" :
     {"summary": "Test Cal",
     "description": "test",
     "timezone" : "xxxx"}
 });
```

Is there anyway to now determine the calendarId? Right now an event is added to the "primary" calendar.

```
var request=gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
             "calendarId": "primary",
             resource:{
                 "summary":.....
```

How can I add the event to the newly created calendar?

Comment: When adding a calendar events, if you give calendar id as "primary", event is added to your primary calendar. If you want to add event to secondary calendar, you have to give this calendar id while creating event. In your calendar->settings->click on the calendar you want->in calendar address check for calendar id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I literally just had to solve the same problem:

```
var calendarID;
var req = gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list({});
    req.execute(function(resp) {
        for (var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
            if (resp.items[i].summary === "Newly Created Schedule") {
                console.log("Newly Created Schedule ID: " + resp.items[i].id);
                calendarID = resp.items[i].id;
                break;
            }
        }
```